# How to make site password protected in windows azure?

Tags: azure

We are working on an application in Windows Azure environment. We are about to finish the dev process. Soon we will move it to live server. For initial few days we want that website to be only accessible for few users. My question is how we can make the website password protected in Azure environment? Please suggest.

Thanks,
Rahul K

Comment: See my tutorial Deploy a Secure ASP.NET MVC 5 app with Membership, OAuth, and SQL Database to an Azure Website  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't use a simple ASP.NET Forms Authentication setup?

You can see how JD Meier sets up forms authentication to work with table storage [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2010/03/18/asp-net-forms-authentication-to-azure-table-storage.aspx).

And then JD Meier shows how to set up forms auth with Azure and SQL Azure [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2010/03/24/how-to-use-asp-net-forms-auth-with-sql-server.aspx).

If the user attempts to access pages that they haven't been authenticated to, they'll be redirected back to the login page (or whatever page you want to redirect them to).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks David for replying and sharing your thought. We are using the authentication. User wont be access the section on which they dont have permission to view. We are about to go live and test the site in beta environment. That's why we want site to be run in password protection environment. Please watch video by useing this url it shows what i am trying to achieve.  http://61.246.241.36/download/example.swf  Please suggest. Thanks once again for taking your time and replying my post.